# How can I hook into an entityform submission?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I've got entity forms installed, and I'd like to use some db_queries when a particular entity form is submitted, as to make use of the information filled out on that entity form.

Is this possible, and which hook should I use?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right, you should use the following hook to capture a submission:

```
hook_entityform_insert($entityform)
```

As described in the comments at the top of entityform.api.php:

```
* Entityform and Entityform type are standard entities using the Entity API module.
* The standard Entity hooks are availabe for them.
* Including
*  ...
*  hook_entityform_insert
```

Hope this helps

Addition:

here is the sample code I used:

```
function mymodule_entityform_insert($entityform){
  dsm($entityform);
}
```

and it did get triggered as soon as I submitted an EntityForm.

Comment: Hi David, I just tried this hook and it did work. I updated my answer above. Let me know if this still is not clear.

Comment: the hook works for me.